# Speeding up page switching xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have an app, with a first run screen and then a tabbed main interface.
On start up of the app, if they've never loaded it before, it opens the first run screen and prompts them to configure some settings.

I do this here, in the App.xaml.cs

```
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bool first_run = Preferences.Get("first_run", true);

            if (first_run)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstRun());
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new MainTabbedPage();
            }

        }
```

So, after the settings, there's a button that takes you to the main app, which I do like this.

```
        private void FinishSetup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Preferences.Set("first_run", false);
            LoadingIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainTabbedPage();
        }
```

So I'm sure that this probably isn't the most ideal way to switch pages, as the ui freezes until the page finishes switching, so the ActivityIndicator isn't able to actually show. Also it takes about 3 seconds to finish switching pages, so I need to figure out a way to either speed it up, or at least give the user indication that the app is working.

Comment: you need to start by figuring out why your tab page is slow to initialize - look at what you're doing in the constructors of each page, etc

Comment: @AdamMasters **Also it takes about 3 seconds to finish switching pages**, I use your code to test, it switch pages quickly, so why you need to 3 seconds, please provide more code here about FirstRun Page.